# How to get Json Data in Listview Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

> Goodmorning all .I am beginner in Xamarin.Forms. I am trying to learn how to get data in Listview with webservices.
>
> My json format :

`{ 
"contacts": [ 
   { 
       "name": "Clark Kent", 
    "email": "mmguy@planet.com" 
    },
    {   "name": "Bruce Wayne",
     "email": "ceo@wayne.net" 
     },
     {  "name": "Tony Stark", 
    "email": "playboy@stark.com" 
    }, 
        ]
}`

> I want to get this Data in Listview. Please help How to call Url and this data in Listview. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just deserialize your json data and bind that deserialized json data to your listview.

**xaml.cs page:**

```
IEnumerable<ContactModel> contactList {get; set;}
contactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ContactModel>>(json);
var listView = new ListView();
listView.ItemsSource =contactList;
```

**xaml page:**

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="name"/>
                        <Label Text="email"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: can you provide project setup?@Hitesh patil